Concerning Lüroth theorem for $k \subset k(f,g) \subseteq k(t)$
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.
Lüroth theorem says that a field $L$, $k \subset L \subset k(t)$ containing a nonconstant polynomial over $k$ is equal to $k(h)$ for some $h \in k[t]$.
More precisely, in Lüroth theorem $h \in k(t)$, and E. Noether has proved that $h \in k[t]$, see "Selected Topics on Polynomials" by A. Schinzel.
Given $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in k[t]$, $k \subset k(f,g) \subseteq k(t)$,
Lüroth-Noether theorem says that $k(f,g)=k(h)$ for some $h=h(t) \in k[t]$.
I see that $\deg_t(h) | \deg_t(f)$ and $\deg_t(h) | \deg_t(g)$;
indeed, $k(f) \subseteq k(f,g)=k(h) \subseteq k(t)$, so $\deg_t(h) | [k(t):k(f)]=\deg_t(f)$, and $k(g) \subseteq k(f,g)=k(h) \subseteq k(t)$, so $\deg_t(h) | [k(t):k(g)]=\deg_t(g)$.
Therefore, $\deg_t(h) | \gcd(\deg_t(f),\deg_t(g))$.
In the special case where $\gcd(\deg_t(f),\deg_t(g))=1$, we have $\deg_t(h)=1$, so $h=at+b$ for some $0 \neq a,b \in k$, hence $k(f,g)=k(h)=k(t)$.
Notice that the other direction is not true in general: for $f=t^3, g=t^6+t^2$, we have $k(f,g)=k(t^3,t^6+t^2)=k(t^3,t^2)=k(t)$, but $\gcd(\deg_t(f),\deg_t(g))=\gcd(3,6)=3$, not $1$.

Question 1: Is there something interesting that can be said about such $h$, in addition to $\deg_t(h) | \gcd(\deg_t(f),\deg_t(g))$? Is there an algorithm how to find such $h$? I do not have the quoted book.

For $f=t^3, g=t^6+t^2$, we see that there is a map $E: k[t] \times k[t] \to k[t]$ such that $\gcd(\deg_t(f),\deg_tE(g,f))=1$, $E: (u,v) \mapsto u-v^2$. Here $E(g,f)=g-f^2=t^6+t^2-t^6=t^2$.
Question 2: Is there such $E$ for every pair $f,g$?
See this relevant question.
Any hints and comments are welcome! Thank you very much.
